# combining grouped rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, grouping

```
   select *
     into #HoldingTable
     FROM
(Select A,
        B,
    sum(cast (C as money)) as C,
    count(D) as D
        FROM Table1 T1
        WHERE (stuff)
                group by A,B

union all
   Select A,
          B,
   sum(cast (C as money)) as C, 
   count(D) as D
        FROM Table2 T2
        WHERE (stuff)
              group by A,B
) as abc
```

When getting the results if T1 and T2 have results with the same A,B it'll list it in 2 different rows
I want to combine these rows and sum C and D When A and B are the same.

```sql
select * from HoldingTable
```

```
aaa,bbb,10,4
aaa,bbb,5,3
```

Would like it to be

```
aaa,bbb,15,7
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe use just `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Seems like you want a `SUM`.

Comment: I think you could simplify it by doing your select of the 4 columns without the group by in your subquery.  Then outside the subquery you do your aggregations and group by.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler to read and should do the same thing as what you are attempting.

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) AS C, Count(D) AS D
INTO #HoldingTable
FROM (
    SELECT A, B, cast(C AS MONEY) AS C, D
    FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE (stuff)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT A, B, cast(C AS MONEY) AS C, D
    FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE (stuff)
    ) AS abc
GROUP BY A, B
```

You could do the aggregation in both the subquery and outer query as below but that just makes it harder to read IMO.

```
SELECT A, B, Sum(C) AS C, Sum(D) AS D
INTO #HoldingTable
FROM (
    SELECT A, B, sum(cast(C AS MONEY)) AS C, count(D) AS D
    FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE (stuff)
    GROUP BY A, B
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT A, B, sum(cast(C AS MONEY)) AS C, count(D) AS D
    FROM Table2 T2
    WHERE (stuff)
    GROUP BY A, B
    ) AS abc
GROUP BY A, B
```